# php parse xml with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, xml

I have xml file:

```
<set>
<item>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>title1</title>
</item>
<item>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>title2</title>
</item>
<item>
    <id>3</id>
    <title>title3</title>
    <img>img3</img>
</item> 
</set>
```

And i need to parse only elements with "img" and get "id -> img". I use regular expression

```
preg_match_all('~<item>.*?<id>(.*?)</id>.*?<img>(.*?)</img>.*?</item>~si', $source, $result);
```

and i get `"id" = '1' and "img" = 'img3', but i need "id" = '3' and "img" = 'img3'`.

**Please help me with my regular expression**.

Comment: you should use XML parsers in PHP for this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't parse html file with regex. If you wanna solution use regex then you could try the below.

```
'~<item>.*?<id>((?:(?!<id>).)*?)</id>(?:(?!<item>).)*<img>(.*?)</img>.*?</item>~si'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/39)

`(?:(?!<id>).)*?` Non-greedy match of any character but not of `<id>`, zero or more times.

Comment: thanks.  And thanks for this site regex101.com. very useful

Comment: yep, you could play with that..